# What does /dev/sda in Linux mean?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

What does

```
/dev/sda
```

stand for? What does it mean?

I have both *Fedora* and *Ubuntu* installed and if I explore them using *Ext2explore* from Windows, I see these names:

```
/dev/sda6
/dev/sda9
```

Please explain to me what that means. I'm referring to the numbers and also the `/dev/sda/` part.

Answer (score 215):

**TL;DR**: It has to do with the way Linux (and other Unixes as well) name their drives, much in the way that Windows uses C:, D:, etc. (**NOTE**: This is what we call a metaphor. In other words, a blatant lie that helps people understand without being even remotely accurate. Read on for a more detailed explanation...)

- `/dev/` is the part in the Unix directory tree that contains all "device" files -- Unix traditionally treats just about everything you can access as a file to read from or write to.
- **sd** originally identified a [SCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI) device, but since the proliferation of USB (and other removable) data carriers, it became a catch-all for any block device (another Unix term; in this context, anything capable of carrying data) that wasn't already accessible via IDE. When SATA came around, the developers figured it'd be much easier *and* much more convenient for everyone to add it into the existing framework rather than write a whole new framework.
- The letter immediately after **sd** signifies the order in which it was first found -- a,b,c...z, Aa...Az... etc. (Not that there are many situations in the real world where more than 26 discrete block devices are on the same bus...)
- Finally, the number after that signifies the partition on the device. Note that because of the rather [haphazard way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) PCs handle partitioning, there are only four "primary" partitions, so the numbering will be slightly off from the actual count. This isn't a terrible problem as the main purpose for the naming scheme is to have a unique and recognizable identifier for each partition found in this manner...

To answer your specific question: `/dev/sda9` means the ninth partition on the first drive.

Comment: /dev/sd[A-Z][a-z] actually is considered invalid by AWS now, unless it requires extra configuration.

Comment: *shouldn't* -- the dev-by-UUID nodes should be symlinks.

Comment: A metaphor is usually related in some sort of tangential way that is more closely related to the addressee's experience than the concept or thing one wishes to explain. So one might explain the workings of a processor in terms of tractors and muddy boots to a farmer, for example. The hope is the addressee will be able to utilise the symbolic link(s) in order to mentally construct a working model of whatever the addresser is describing, without first-hand knowledge. So it's only really a lie in the same way a block-chain is a lie about a pass-phrase. In fact, a blockchain is a sort of metaphor.

Comment: Note that with NVMe instead of SATA, the name of the first device is `/dev/nvme0n1`

Comment: Does this mean that SATA piggybacks on the SCSI framework? i.e. if you don't include SCSI in the kernel you wouldn't be able to mount SATA drives?

Comment: @linuxgnuru Judging by the output of `lsmod` on one of my systems, the answer to that is yes -- `scsi_mod` is required by `libata`. Then again, `scsi_mod` is also required by `usb_storage` so there you go...

Comment: @Shadur what if on `df -h` I see `sda` and `sde` but not `sdb`?

Comment: @mrgloom drive 'letters' are not automatically resequenced every time they change -- if I had to guess, I'd say you've plugged and unplugged several USB data carriers since the last time this system was rebooted.

Answer (score 26):

/dev is your filesystem representation of devices your system understands - providing a mechanism for applications to access data on the device without needing to know specifically what the device is.

**sd** is for (originally) scsi disk devices, however it seems to now refer to removable devices in general and SATA devices

and the letter is just the number of the device, starting at a, with the number indicating the partition.

Answer (score 22):

`sd` originates from the driver `sd-mod`. It literally stands for **s**csi **d**isk.

The reason (S)ATA disks are also listed as SCSI disks is, SCSI commands pretty much provides a superset of features that can be provided by ATA commands, therefore modern systems (including Windows, AFAIK) will have an implementation of SCSI-ATA Translation Layer (SATL) in the system (in Linux it is provided by the `libata` driver) to talk to the (S)ATA disks, while the upper layer of the system can be generalized.

As you may not aware of, USB drives "speaks" SCSI (i.e. takes and responds to SCSI commands), no matter if it supports the USB Attached SCSI Protocol or not. Also, most of the USB HDDs/SSDs are SATA disks bridged to USB. For those the bridge provides the SATL, but not the operating system.