# Mounting USB drive at boot up on a virtualized instance of fedora

Tags: linux, mount, fedora, fstab

I am running Fedora inside of a Type 1 hypervisor(ESXi). In the VM's settings, I am making 2 USB devices available to it, both are of the exact model and storage capacities, however, one is named "AZS" and the other "ZSA". I want to edit my `fstab` so that "AZS" gets mounted to `~/1usb` and "ZSA" is mounted to `~/2usb` at boot up, the problem that I foresee is that I have noticed that the partition that gets assigned to my drives is not always the same. There are only two partitions that I've seen assigned to the drives `/dev/sdb1` or `/dev/sdc1`, but my flash drives seem to assign to either or, not one in particular. Perhaps this has something to do with the rebooting of the ESXi host or the Fedora guest?

How do I make sure that the flash drives get mounted to the correct mount point at boot up?

Comment: Can you mount them by UUID or Volume?  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#Identifying_filesystems  Perhaps with `nofail` in case you forgot to connect them.

Comment: @lx07
Thanks for the link, I do not know enough about Linux or file systems, so my question is: how do I distinguish between the UUID of `/dev/sdb1` vs that of my flash drive? Or does `/dev/sdb1` only have a UUID when there is something attached?

Comment: The UUID is the ID of the partition and is only there when it is attached. You can see it with `sudo blkid`.  I'll put it in an answer as it is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `blkid` you can see the UUID of the partitions you want to attach.  For example this is two attached USB - the second having 4 partitions.

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="A USB Key" UUID="2E2C1CA92C1C6DD9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="001b9586-01"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="bbbab20e-f534-3125-aa76-9307200ac097" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="ESP" PARTUUID="9c2b51dc-7fb7-4b7a-87c7-ab99e6541a3c"
/dev/sdc2: LABEL_FATBOOT="USB_FAT" LABEL="USB_FAT" UUID="63DE-0F12" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Microsoft basic data" PARTUUID="ac46c74a-5db6-42a2-a3ad-997c395bd8e5"
/dev/sdc3: UUID="4d6e9ffd-cd4e-38e2-932c-17d0f1c634b5" LABEL="Preboot" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="Apple HFS/HFS+" PARTUUID="2db5ea6a-e921-4ee6-a5e5-884487a5b0e1"
/dev/sdc4: UUID="6ab50862-5de9-3c8b-af2e-615f73d23c67" LABEL="Recovery HD" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="Recovery HD" PARTUUID="43e67dda-00dd-4844-a570-883ea8dfca6c"
```

To mount what is currently at sdb1 and sdc2 you make a couple of directories :

```
# mkdir /mnt/usb1
# mkdir /mnt/usb2
```

Then add records to `/etc/fstab` but specifying setting `UUID=` to the value you got from `blkid` rather than the device name as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683034/how-to-automatically-mount-usb-flash-drive-at-startup) on Ask Ubuntu.  Note that you can use `LABEL=` or `PARTLABEL=` instead if you prefer.

```
UUID=63DE-0F12          /mnt/usb1       vfat            auto,nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
UUID=2E2C1CA92C1C6DD9   /mnt/usb2       ntfs            auto,nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

If you mount them the correct UUID goes to correct mountpoint :

```
# mount -a
# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    82G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     4G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0    10G  0 part /
├─sda5   8:5    0   9.9G  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0  12.9G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1  14.9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14.9G  0 part /mnt/usb2
sdc      8:32   1  29.8G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   1   200M  0 part 
├─sdc2   8:34   1     8G  0 part /mnt/usb1
├─sdc3   8:35   1  20.4G  0 part 
└─sdc4   8:36   1   1.2G  0 part
```

Even if you then pull out and swap them - the device names change to sdd1 and sde2 but are still mounted in same mount point.

```
# mount -a
# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    82G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     4G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0    10G  0 part /
├─sda5   8:5    0   9.9G  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0  12.9G  0 part 
sdd      8:48   1  14.9G  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   1  14.9G  0 part /mnt/usb2
sde      8:64   1  29.8G  0 disk 
├─sde1   8:65   1   200M  0 part 
├─sde2   8:66   1     8G  0 part /mnt/usb1
├─sde3   8:67   1  20.4G  0 part 
└─sde4   8:68   1   1.2G  0 part
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very thorough and helped me understand the concepts. 

One last thing, what is the proper term to use to refer to an entity such as: `/dev/sdb1`. This confuses me because I think that this is being referenced as the partition, but to my knowledge, the partition would be inside of the flash drive and `/dev/sdb1` seems to be inside of my OS.

Comment: The partition **is** on flash drive.  The `/dev/sdb1` is a filesystem representation of this partition that the OS can understand and would normally be called a partition to make life easier.  Similarly `/dev/sdb` would be called a device even though the 'real' device is the physical object.  Have a look at [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/558156/ddg#558163) for more details/discussion of this.